# How can I connect to the IPFS network using web3.storage API in Django?

Tags: django, api

Web3.Storage site can be used to upload files, but it's also quick and easy to create and run a simple upload script — making it especially convenient to add large numbers of files. The script contains logic to upload a file to Web3.Storage and get a content identifier (CID) in return which would basically be the address to access files. However, in the documentation, the in-built functions are given using Node.js. How can this be done using Django or any other Python based framework?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially write a wrapper for web3storage http api in django: https://web3.storage/docs/reference/http-api/

They have expanded their client libraries to include Golang as well but since we know the API spec it should be doable to make a django wrapper

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33115896)